# Modifying Json result by adding key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How will i change my json result from

```
["Published with github","ZA Publications","Apress","Really","Neal"]
```

To

```
[
    {"Name" : "Published with github"},
    {"Name" : "ZA Publications"},
    {"Name" : "Apress"},
    {"Name" : "Really"},
    {"Name" : "Neal"}
]
```

correct me if i am wrong somewhere, if you need much detail

Thank you

Comment: How can we correct if there's no attemps? We need to see what you have tried so that we can point out where's the problem.

Comment: Anyway `var res = json.map(function(item) {return {Name: item};}); probably solves.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function to convert it into an array of objects

```
var x = ["Published with github","ZA Publications","Apress","Really","Neal"];

var y = $(x).map(function(i,v){
    return {'name':v};
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3e1ex6un/)

Comment: Javascript has a built-in `map` function for Arrays. No need for jQuery.

Comment: In this case i am getting empty object like "Object[ ]" while debugging

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function as a staring point. After understanding it you could use MAP.

```
function addName() {
 var json1 = ["Published with github","ZA Publications","Apress","Really","Neal"];
 for(var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++)
 {
  // Change "Published with github" to "Name: Published with github"
  json1[i] = { Name: json1[i] };
 };
}
```

Comment: Yep, this clear example helps me understand the situation, thanks

Comment: Ok I have another problem now, the result i have got from this is something like this

[Object { Name="abc pub"}, Object { Name="new pub"}, Object { Name="pub pub"}]

How will i create Key: value pairs from this for later use???

Comment: What kind of key:value pairs do you want?

Comment: Sorry if i am not able to explain my situation properly but what i want to do is to populate a third party control kendoDropDownList from this result that require dataTextField, dataValueField, and dataSource: properties, i am assigning json1 to DataSource which i can and its ok, but when setting dataTextField: "Name" and DataValuefield: "Name", its not working

Comment: how will i populate drop down list from this?